# isin only returning first line from csv

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading from a sqlite3 db into a df:

```
          id symbol                                               name
0          1   QCLR  Global X Funds Global X NASDAQ 100 Collar 95-1...
1          2    LCW                    Learn CW Investment Corporation
2          3    BUG          Global X Funds Global X Cybersecurity ETF
3          4   LDOS                              Leidos Holdings, Inc.
4          5    LDP  COHEN & STEERS LIMITED DURATION PREFERRED AND ...
...      ...    ...                                                ...
10999  11000   ERIC                Ericsson American Depositary Shares
11000  11001    EDI  Virtus Stone Harbor Emerging Markets Total Inc...
11001  11002    EVX                  VanEck Environmental Services ETF
11002  11003   QCLN  First Trust NASDAQ Clean Edge Green Energy Ind...
11003  11004    DTB  DTE Energy Company 2020 Series G 4.375% Junior...

[11004 rows x 3 columns]
```

Then I have a `symbols.csv` file which I want to use to filter the above df:

```
AKAM
AKRO
```

Here's how I've tried to do it:

```
origin_symbols = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT  id, symbol, name from stock", conn)
mikey_symbols = pd.read_csv("symbols.csv")
df = origin_symbols[origin_symbols['symbol'].isin(mikey_symbols)]
```

But for some reason I only get the first line returned from the csv:

```
        id symbol                                    name
6475  6476   AKAM  Akamai Technologies, Inc. Common Stock
1 df
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert csv file to `Series`, here is added column name and for `Series` select it (e.g. by position):

```
mikey_symbols = pd.read_csv("symbols.csv", names=['tmp']).iloc[:, 0]
#or by column name
#mikey_symbols = pd.read_csv("symbols.csv", names=['tmp'])['tmp']
```

And then remove possible traling spaces in both by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df = origin_symbols[origin_symbols['symbol'].str.strip().isin(mikey_symbols.str.strip())]
```